# How can I return 404 for specified existing file in apache and nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to return 404 error for some specified files like 'config.php' . How can I do it with '.htaccess' in Apache? And in nginx without htaccess? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

NGINX:

```
location = /config.php {
    return 404;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `.htaccess` with Apache, and it's actually only recommended as a [last resort](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when). Likewise, mod_rewrite should only be used if necessary: [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#:~:text=It%20describes%20perhaps%20one%20of,fragile%2C%20and%20hard%20to%20maintain.).

You can use both [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) from mod_alias to return 404:

- `Redirect 404 /config.php`
- `RedirectMatch 404 ^/config.php$`

You can place them directly in your server configuration, or in your [Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html), e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"

    Redirect 404 /config.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` on Apache (using mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^config\.php$ - [R=404]
```

Assuming `/config.php` in the document root.