# Apache Filesmatch regex issue

Tags: apache-2.4, regex, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to block all files that contains the keyword **cpf**

and I've entered this into the apache2 configuration:

```
<FilesMatch "cpf.*$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

and this blocked a file called **name.cpf**, but not **name.cpfs** and **name.cpfs.bak**

me and regex isn't compatible..

and if possible, throw a 404 not found instead of access denied?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the regex. For 404 see this answer https://serverfault.com/a/1020454/23022

Comment: @AlexD me either, but if  I'm entering name.cpfs the server will send me the file...